# I uninstalled Visual Studio and now Pycharm community won't run Python programs

Tags: visual-studio, pycharm, jetbrains-toolbox

I'm getting two simultaneous error messages one in the console (1) the other as a popup on the de-bugger icon on the left side-bar (2):

1. No Python at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python.exe'
2. Connection to Python debugger failed Socket closed

The programs I ran were one's I wrote before and run on Anaconda's IDLE

Solutions I've tried:

1. Re-install Pycharm through Jetbrains Tool box.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall python from https://www.python.org/downloads/

install it and delete your venv folder and recreate it using the new installed python.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new env using Anaconda in Pycharm that fixed it.
I think it first used the Visual studio file for my last enviroment and when i uninstalled VS it took the program file the env was using with it.